# For django testing, how do I use keepdb with mariadb

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I have a database with a lot of nonmanaged tables which I'm using for a django app. For testing I'm wanting to use the --keepdb option so that I don't have to repopulate these tables every time. I'm using MariaDB for my database. If I don't use the keepdb option everything works fine, the test database gets created and destroyed properly.

But when I try to run the test keeping the database:

$ python manage.py test --keepdb

I get the following error:

Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test_livedb` ;\n                    SET sql_note' at line 2")

I assume that this is an issue with a different syntax between MariaDB and MySQL. Is there anyway to get the keepdb option to work with MariaDB?

thanks very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things - check out Factory Boy (for creating test data) and I would suggest checking out Pytest as well. With non-managed tables, the issue I think you'll run into is that (at least in my experience) django won't create them in the test environment and you end up running into issues because there is no `migration` file to create those tables (since they're unmanaged). Django runs the `migration` files when creating the test environment.

With Pytest you can run with a `--nomigrations` flag which builds your test database directly off the models (thus creating the tables you need for your unmanaged models).

If you combine Pytest and Factory Boy you should be able to come up with the ability to setup your test data so it works as expected, is repeatable and testable without issue.

I actually approach it like this (slightly hacky, but it works with our complex setup):

On my model:

```
class Meta(object):
    db_table = 'my_custom_table'
    managed = getattr(settings, 'UNDER_TEST', False)
```

I create the `UNDER_TEST` variable in `settings.py` like this:

```
# Create global variable that will tell if our application is under test
UNDER_TEST = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'test')
```

That way - when the application is `UNDER_TEST` the model is marked as managed (and Pytest will create the appropriate DB table). Then FactoryBoy handles putting all my test data into that table (either in `setUp` of the test or elsewhere) so I can test against it.

That's my suggestion - others might have something a little more clear or cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: This bug was introduced in Django 2.0.0 and fixed in Django 2.1.3 (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29827)